# gawk `fflush()` doesn't seem to be working correctly when trying to use a multi-char RS record separator with a '[' in it

Tags: awk

**EDIT**

As my original question wasn't clear. Here is a better version:

When executing the following from bash on a xterm-256color terminal:

```
(echo -ne "[0/3] one<RS>"; sleep 2; echo -ne "[1/3] two<RS>"; sleep 2; echo -ne "[2/3] three<RS>"; sleep 2; echo -en "[3/3] The end.") | gawk 'BEGIN { RS="<RS>"; ORS="" } /\[/ { printf("X%sY\n", $0); fflush(); next }'
```

using a multi-character RS value `"<RS>"` then this does was I expect: each line, ending with `<RS>`, is printed immediately. Most notably the `[0/3] one` is printed immediately, and also between `[2/3] three` and `[3/3] The end.` there is a delay. Everything is printed one line at a time, precisely as it was generated by the bash script: immediately being flushed.

However, when putting a `[` (square bracket open) in the RS sequence, each output line gets delayed until the next record was received. For example:

```
(echo -ne "[0/3] one<R[S>"; sleep 2; echo -ne "[1/3] two<R[S>"; sleep 2; echo -ne "[2/3] three<R[S>"; sleep 2; echo -en "[3/3] The end.") | gawk 'BEGIN { RS="<R[[]S>"; ORS="" } /\[/ { printf("X%sY\n", $0); fflush(); next }'
```

I tried using `\0133` instead of `[[]`, but that doesn't seem to work.

OLD POST:

When executing the following from bash on a xterm-256color terminal:

```
(echo -ne "\r[0/2] hello\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -ne "\r[1/2] world\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -en "\r[2/2] The end.\n") | gawk 'BEGIN { RS="\033[[]K"; ORS="" } /^\r\[/ { printf("X%sY", $0); fflush(stdout); next }'
```

I see:

```
...2 second delay...
[0/2] helloY
...2 second delay...
[2/2] The end.
Y
```

All on one line. The `X[1/2] worldY` is also written, but immediately overwritten by the `[2/2] The end.`

Apparently, upon receiving the first string, `[0/2] hello\e[K`, gawk is not flushing the output; either the RS is not doing what I expect it to do, or the `fflush` is not working. Upon receiving the second string (after a 2 second delay) the `hello` string is received and/or flushed - but the second string is -again- not flushed. It must have been received however, or else the `/^\r\[/` would not have triggered (gawk prints something upon receiving the second (world) line).

What I'd expect is to see:

```
[0/2] helloY
...2 second delay...
[1/2] worldY
...2 second delay...
[2/2] The end.
Y
```

all on one line (except that last Y), where the `X` is never visible because it is followed by a carriage return and a `[` which overwrites it.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I get awk to show all the three records?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try it without all the control chars first and once you have that working THEN add back the `\r`s, once you have that working THEN and back escape sequences (or vice-versa)?

As you can see if you just remove the `\r`s, the `RS` is behaving as it should and the `fflush()` is behaving as it should, and `awk` IS printing all 3 records:

```
$ (echo -ne "[0/2] hello\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -ne "[1/2] world\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -en "[2/2] The end.\n") | gawk 'BEGIN { RS="\033[[]K"; ORS="" } /\[/ { printf("X%sY\n", $0); fflush(); next }'
X[0/2] helloY
X[1/2] worldY
X[2/2] The end.
Y
```

You can also see that with your original script by piping it to `cat -v` to print the `\r`s as `^M`:

```
$ (echo -ne "\r[0/2] hello\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -ne "\r[1/2] world\e[K"; sleep 2; echo -en "\r[2/2] The end.\n") | gawk 'BEGIN { RS="\033[[]K"; ORS="" } /^\r\[/ { printf("X%sY", $0); fflush(stdout); next }' | cat -v
X^M[0/2] helloYX^M[1/2] worldYX^M[2/2] The end.
Y
```

I changed `fflush(stdout)` to `fflush()` in  the first script because the `stdout` arg you're passing is an uninitialized, and so null, variable which does nothing beyond what the default without args does - flush all open output files and pipes. If you ONLY wanted stdout flushed that'd be `fflush("/dev/stdout")` with gawk.

Comment: I am sorry to not have been clear enough. The problem has nothing to do with the \r, which I probably should have removed for this test case. The problem is that any line (ending on `\e[K`) is only flushed after the NEXT line was received. Also your examples show this behavior: instead of immediately printing "X[0/2] helloY", it waits 2 seconds (until after "X[1/2] worldY" was received), and at the end it finally really flushes everything and prints both "X[1/2] worldY" and "X[2/2] The end.\n". What I need is that it prints each record immediately and not only after the next one is received.

Comment: I edited the question to more clearly explain what the question is ;).

Answer (score 0):

it has nothing to do with the `fflush()` - carriage ***return***, `\015` aka `\r`, does exactly what the name suggests in the terminal screen (think what it does on a typewriter)

- simply "***returning***" the position marker to start of line, without actually moving to a new line; overwriting existing chars as new ones are being printed out

that said, `\r` can sometimes be leveraged to your advantage to create neatly formatted output while still being counted only as 1 single line by `cat -n` :

> ```
> gfactor 12991671785233443057 | mawk NF=NF OFS='\f\r\t' | gcat -n
> ```

```
1   12991671785233443057: 3 7 17 31 67 127 257 8191 65537
```

….becomes…

```
1   12991671785233443057:
    3
    7
    17
    31
    67
    127
    257
    8191
    65537
```

The backspace `\b` is more fun in that sense :

> ```
> gfactor 12991671785233443057 | mawk NF=NF OFS='\f\b\b' | gcat -n
> ```

```
 1  12991671785233443057:
                       3
                      7
                     17
                     31
                     67
                     127
                      257
                       8191
                         65537
```

Comment: I am sorry to not have been clear enough. The problem has nothing to do with the \r, which I probably indeed should have removed for this test case. The problem is that any line (ending on `\e[K`) is only flushed after the NEXT line was received. What I need is that it prints each record immediately and not only after the next one is received. Note that it works when I replace `\e[K`/`RS` with a single character.

Comment: I edited the question to more clearly explain what the question is ;).

Comment: @CarloWood : you just wanna colorize output assuming delay from the pipe ? run this : `jot - 0.000 6.111 0.857 | mawk 'system("sleep .19")( $!NF=(___)((_^=_<_)+int(rand()*(-_+(_+=++_)^_)))__$!_ ("\33")__)' ___=' \33[38;5;' __='m\33[K'` - if it works on your side, you can easily modify it for your coloring needs - just get rid of the `system( sleep )` portion that simulates delay from the pipe

Comment: Heh - colors? No, I wanted to filter the output of ninja while still showing it's progress messages in real-time. I decided that awk can't do it because it delays records when RS contains a reg-exp, so I wrote a little C program to do it.

Comment: @CarloWood : which `awk` you're using though ? if you're using `mawk`, run it as `mawk -Wi -- '{ … }'` to activate the unbuffered output mode … maybe it works ….. u wrote a C program just cuz you need a progress bar ??